# I'm building a media player app, my application is getting a fatal exception

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I don't know what to do now, I'm new to Android.

```
package com.example.macbookpro.myplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioPlayer extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    ImageView btn_play;
    Button btn_pause;
    ImageView btn_next;
    ImageView btn_prev;
    ImageView btn_forward;
    ImageView btn_backward;
    TextView song_title;
    int currentsongindex;
    int seekForwardTime = 5000;
    int seekBackwardTime = 5000;
    private Utilities utilities;
    Handler mHandler1=new Handler();
    SeekBar song_progressbar;
    final ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<File>();

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_player);

        btn_play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btn_next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btn_prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);
        btn_forward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_forward);
        btn_backward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_backwrd);
        song_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw);
        song_progressbar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.song_progressbar);

        song_progressbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);


        try {
            PlaySongtwo(getIntent().getStringExtra("index"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String[] sec = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("index2");
        currentsongindex = Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getStringExtra("positionofcurrentsong")));

        utilities = new Utilities();

        // Button for playing the song

        btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();

                        btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);

                    } else {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.start();
                           btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                    }
                }


            }
        });

        // Button for the next song in the list

        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.e("currenttt song is ",currentsongindex+"");
                if(currentsongindex < (sec.length-1)){

                    int cc=currentsongindex+1;
                    Log.e("value in cc",cc+"");
                    try {
                        PlaySongtwo(sec[cc]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.e("next song number is ",cc +"");

                    currentsongindex = currentsongindex +1;
                }else {
                    try {
                        PlaySongtwo(sec[0]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    currentsongindex = 0;
                }


            }
        });

        //Button for the previous song in the list

        btn_prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentsongindex > 0){
                    int prevsong= currentsongindex-1;
                    try {
                        PlaySongtwo(sec[prevsong]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.e("prev song",prevsong+"");
                    currentsongindex = prevsong;
                }else {
                    try {
                        PlaySongtwo(String.valueOf((sec.length-1)));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    currentsongindex = sec.length-1;

                }

            }
        });

        //Button for fast-forwarding the song


        btn_forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration() ){
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else {
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }


            }
        });


        //Button for fast-backwarding the song

        btn_backward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int currentPostion = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                if(currentPostion - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    mp.seekTo(currentPostion - seekBackwardTime);
                }else {
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });


    }



    private void PlaySongtwo(String path) throws IOException {
        try {
            String songname = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            song_title.setText(songname);
            mp.reset();
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);
            mp.setDataSource(AudioPlayer.this, myUri);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            song_progressbar.setProgress(0);
            song_progressbar.setMax(100);
            updateProgressBar1();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void updateProgressBar1() {
        mHandler1.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask1,100);
    }
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask1=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            long currentDuration=mp.getCurrentPosition();


            int progress=(int)(utilities.getProgresspercentage(currentDuration,totalDuration));
            song_progressbar.setProgress(progress);

            mHandler1.postDelayed(this,100);

        }
    };

    @Override
        protected void onDestroy ()
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            mp.release();
        }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        mHandler1.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler1.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask1);
        int totalDuration=mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition=utilities.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),totalDuration);
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
        updateProgressBar1();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
    enter code here
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm facing.

```
11-06 13:30:03.935 1060-1060/com.example.macbookpro.myplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
11-06 13:30:04.031 1060-1060/com.example.macbookpro.myplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
11-06 13:30:22.260 1060-1060/com.example.macbookpro.myplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-06 13:30:22.261 1060-1060/com.example.macbookpro.myplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.macbookpro.myplayer, PID: 1060
                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                   at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.example.macbookpro.myplayer.AudioPlayer$6.run(AudioPlayer.java:220)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Tip: questions on Stack Overflow are expected to have a bit of effort put into them. Chatty titles, please-halp-me begging, txtspk, all-caps shouting, no paragraph text in the body, and unformatted log excerpts will encourage readers to roll their eyes and hit the downvote button. It is ideal, also, to show that when you received an exception, you did some research - don't make asking a question the first thing you do! You're not stuck until you've spent a solid half an hour or so researching the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to getDuration before your MediaPlayer is ready to be used.
Make sure you're setting all controls that interact with the mediaplayer.